# CMake command for paths are equal

Tags: c++, cmake

Is there a CMake command that returns true if and only if two paths point to the same place (even if the paths are not verbatim equal strings)?

Something like

```
set(x ../foo)
set(y C:/cmaketest/foo)
if (x PATHEQUAL y)
{
   message(status "YAY")
}
```

Comment: http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-July/030672.html

Comment: @sharth I'm assuming your saying to convert both values to absolute paths using this method, then probably also convert them to cmake paths, and then compare the string as equal after, which works, but seems like alot more work than it should be...I was wondering if there was a built-in command.

Comment: I've expanded that url to a full answer. If that's not what you are looking for, let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should mostly work. The one case that it doesn't appear to take into account is filesystems that are not case-sensitive (This includes the default file systems on OS X and Windows, but does not include Linux).

```
get_filename_component(x ./foo.txt   ABSOLUTE)
get_filename_component(y ././foo.txt ABSOLUTE)

if (x STREQUAL y)
    message(STATUS "Strings are Equal")
else()
    message(STATUS "Strings are Not Equal")
endif()
```

This outputs:

```
[11:55am][wlynch@watermelon blah] touch foo.txt
[11:55am][wlynch@watermelon blah] cmake . |& head -n 1
-- Strings are Equal
```

Comment: What if I want to compare `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` I'm not able to dereference at the good level. Ether it finds a diff between SOURCE ans BINARY, or it finds same value when they are different.

Comment: You may want to use `get_filename_component(foo bar REALPATH)` instead of `ABSOLUTE`, since `REALPATH` resolves symlinks, too. That will make your answer also handle the case when the inputs are two different symlinks that resolve to the same thing.

Of course, that might not actually be what someone is trying to do...